# Counting occurrences of multiple strings in multiple files

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I've got multiple text files in a folder. For each one, I want to search for 3 different strings and add the counts of those strings together, then output them to a file.

This works for counting a single string in the different files:

```
for /f "delims==" %%a in ('dir /b "%CD%\*.txt"') do findstr /r /n "^.*SEARCH_STRING_1.*$" "%%~dpnxa" | find /c "SEARCH_STRING_1" >> "%%~dpacounts.txt"
```

This results in a file with a count on a new line for each file in the folder.  How can I search for "SEARCH_STRING_1", "SEARCH_STRING_2" and "SEARCH_STRING_3", add the counts together, and output them to the file the same way?

Comment: If one line contains more than one string, should it be counted as one or more?

Comment: more I suppose, but that wouldn't happen in the files I'm dealing with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a line with two matches should be counted as only one or if there is no possibility of a line containing more than one match

```dos
findstr /c:"string1" /c:"string2" /c:"string3" *.txt | find /c /v "" > counts.txt
```

If one line could contain more than one match and each match must be counted

```dos
(
    findstr /c:"string1" *.txt
    findstr /c:"string2" *.txt
    findstr /c:"string3" *.txt
) | find /c /v "" > counts.txt
```

Of course, adjust the `findstr` switches to your needs

Comment: the first one works great until I add the `| find /c /v ""` bit.  Then it throws a bunch of `the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.  FINDSTR: Write error`.  It works fine in the command I listed in my question, but not with multiple search strings?

Comment: @Aeon2058, tested and working. If I have to bet there is some syntax problem in your command line or you have another command writing to the output file.